# is there a way to do Linux ifup or ifdown in bash without always having to type sudo first?

Tags: linux, bash, beagleboneblack

For ifup/ifdown, service, and other commands, is there a way around always needing to type sudo first?

Linux version is 3.8.13-bone67

Comment: Either type `sudo -i` or `su -`. Then you're in a root console and any subsequent commands don't need `sudo` before them. Most ways of trying to avoid needing a password can potentially cause a security hole if that's what you're actually trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the simplest way:

add the following in your `~/.bashrc`:

```
alias ifup='sudo /usr/bin/ifup'
```

(or whatever is the path to your `ifup` binary. If you don't know the path, you can find out using `which ifup`)

You then have to enter your password as regular. To also avoid typing the password, you can add an entry into your `sudoers` file.
Use `$ sudo visudo` to edit it (will use the editor defined in `$EDITOR` or `vi`) and add a line like the following to the end:

```
ALL ALL = NOPASSWD: /full/path/and/full/command
```

Sources:

- https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Sudo#Configuration

Comment: It is to note that fiddling with the sudoers file may potentially generate great security risks

Comment: Yes, the need for sudo is usually not without a reason. Each time you circumvent the use of a password, it should be weighed against the introduced risks. Especially when editing the sudoers file without deeper understanding.